# Disconnected from VM

Tags: java, path, global-variables

Each time that I try to debug a code in Itellij, I have this message: **
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58996', transport: 'socket'**

How could I solve it?

Uninstall and dowload Java. Delete and create the code again. Review if the firewall has been blocked the program, and isn't.
[Intellij IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DpmI.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things you can try to solve the problem of being disconnected from the target VM in IntelliJ IDEA:

*Check your firewall settings. Make sure that IntelliJ IDEA is not being blocked by your firewall. You can usually do this by adding an exception for IntelliJ IDEA in your firewall settings.
*Use a different port. The default port for debugging is 5005. If another program is using that port, you can try using a different port. To do this, open the Run/Debug configuration and change the port number in the VM Options field.
*Restart IntelliJ IDEA. Sometimes, a simple restart can solve the problem.
*Reinstall Java. If you've tried all of the above and you're still having problems, you can try reinstalling Java.
If you're still having problems, you can try searching for help on the IntelliJ IDEA forums or submitting a bug report to JetBrains.

Here are some additional things to keep in mind:

Make sure that you're using the latest version of IntelliJ IDEA.
Make sure that your Java installation is up to date.
Make sure that your code is well-formatted and free of errors.
Try debugging a simpler program to see if you can reproduce the problem.
I hope this helps!